# JavaScript Regular Expression to linkify text not in tags

Tags: javascript, expression, linkify

I have been using the following linkify code for a while:

```
return str.replace(/(\s|^)(mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\:\/\/\S+)/g,'$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>')
.replace(/(\s|^)@(\w+)/g, '$1<a class="tweetmention" href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>')
.replace(/(\s|^)#(\w+)/g, '$1<a class="tweethash" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">#$2</a>');
```

I now have a scenario where a user can add images, youtube iframes, etc. So I need to wrap links around strings *outside* these tags.

Side note: I can limit what tags can be added and control the format of these tags.

Any suggestions?